# Mask unwanted triangles of tricontour matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `tricontour` to reproduce water content data and I would like to mask the triangles that are interpolated but are not part of the geometry of the surface.

I tried to plot only traingles with a maximum of `radius = 2` (from another previous post):

```
fig, (ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1)

triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)

#plot only triangles with side length smaller max_radius
max_radius = 2
triangles = triang.triangles

#Mask off unwanted triangles.
xtri = x[triangles] - np.roll(x[triangles], 1, axis=1)
ytri = y[triangles] - np.roll(y[triangles], 1, axis=1)
maxi = np.max(np.sqrt(xtri**2 + ytri**2), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(maxi > max_radius)

#tricontour
ax2.tricontour(triang, plausability_control['wc_values'][1], levels=20, linewidths=0.2, colors='k')
cntr2 = ax2.tricontourf(triang, plausability_control['wc_values'][1], levels=20, cmap="RdBu")

cbar2 = fig.colorbar(cntr2, ax=ax2)
cbar2.set_label('(m-3 m3)', loc='center', fontsize=8, rotation=270, labelpad=15)
ax2.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))
ax2.set_title('Reference Scenario: Water Content - time step ' + str(1))

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.savefig('reference_experiment')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

But it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TUBAF\BEAK\scripts\subs\plot_reference.py", line 103, in <module>
    xtri = x[triangles] - np.roll(x[triangles], 1, axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\TUBAF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 984, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)
  File "C:\Users\TUBAF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1019, in _get_with
    return self.loc[key]
  File "C:\Users\TUBAF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 967, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\TUBAF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1189, in _getitem_axis
    raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# meshing with delaunay triangulation 
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)

# mask out invalid data 
mask = TriAnalyzer(triang).get_flat_tri_mask(min_circle_ratio=0.17, rescale=True) 
triang.set_mask(mask)
```